# How to programmatically monitor power consumption on Windows?

Tags: windows, power-management, power-consumption

I'm developing an app to monitor energy consumption of users' computer (for example how much energy it consumes on normal mode and energy save mode, battery status, etc) and I was wondering if there is any built in functionalities in Windows? some tool which can run through commmand line can also help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot measure power consumption from Windows.

You can only make a very rough estimate obtain calculations that consider things as load level for CPU/GPU, estimates for consumption of other components.

The only way you can actually measure the consumption is to use an external power meter.

For the estimates, you can use things like [Joulemeter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/joulemeter-computational-energy-measurement-and-optimization/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a laptop, there is a set of performance counters for battery charge, battery drain, and remaining energy.